# Understanding what (x) and (x_1) are doing in Keras SSD mobile net

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to understand SSD Keras code and have some problem particularly with the Conv2d ,Lambda and Input function.

What I understand so far is that,

Input function will take a tuple of size 3 (lets say (x,y,z)).
Then, I have trouble understanding what are (x),(x_1) and lambda() doing?

```
x = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, img_channels))

x1 = Lambda(lambda z: z,
            output_shape=(img_height, img_width, img_channels),
            name='idendity_layer')(x)
conv1_1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal', kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg), name='conv1_1')(x1)
```

So I am having trouble understanding what (x) and (x1) are doing.
Also what does it mean to make a Lambda() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Keras functional, the result of an operation needs to be passed to the next operation, which you can see from the first and second lines of your example code: `x` is fed into `x1`, just as `x1` is fed into `conv1_1`. The reason they have unique variable names (rather than simply propagating variable `x`) is so they can be referenced several times, if you wish to send a tensor to multiple different operation-routes.

In this case, the input tensor `x` enters the network through `x1`, which is passed to `conv1_1`, among other things. As you can see from the image at the bottom of this post, some layers output to multiple layers. For example, Block 16 passes to Block 17 *and* to the second convolutional layer of the SSD network. Consider the following example code snippet, showing one tensor feeding into multiple layers, and reconvening at the end.

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(28,28,3)

x1 = Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same')(input_tensor)
x2 = Conv2D(64,(2,2),padding='same')(input_tensor)

x1 = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x1)
x2 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x2)

x = concatenate([x1,x2])
x = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(input_tensor, x) # in and out
```

Regarding the Lambda... In this case, the Lambda is superfluous, as Conv2D layer `conv1_1` could have handled its function here, but may have been added for clarity. Since the lambda function inside the Lambda function is essentially just `z : z`, it's not actually performing any operations. *In this case, it's serving as an entry point for tensor `x`.*

[image: SSD MobileNet]

Comment: I see, so basically, x and x_1 are just passing the variable to the Conv2d function?

Comment: `x` is the input tensor, which is entering the network through `x_1`, which passes that same tensor to `conv1_1`, which is where the first actual operations and weights are. Without seeing more of the network, it's hard to say whether `conv1_1` is the only layer that receives the output of the Lambda function, but it *can* be referenced by multiple future layers, since its output has a unique variable name `x_1`.

Comment: The main take-away here is that the output from any layer is assigned to a variable (like `x_1`), and that output becomes the input for whichever layers you please, specified parenthetically at the end of the function. As long as the shapes fit, the tensors will flow. :) `model.summary()` helps with that part.